# How to do svg scaling with Pixi

Tags: svg, vuejs2, pixi.js

I've been trying to do SVG scaling with PIXI but the results are not really what I expected them to be. As you can see in the image, the debian logo, which is a SVG file, seems to be blurry and edgy. Am I writing my code wrong:

Refined from https://github.com/kevguy/D3-Svg-Comparison/blob/master/src/components/SvgCompare.vue:

```
// initialization
this.renderer = new PIXI.Application(800, 600, {backgroundColor: 0x1099bb})  
document.getElementById('svg-canvas').appendChild(this.renderer.view)
this.container = new PIXI.Container()
this.stage = this.renderer.stage
this.stage.addChild(this.container)

// appending the svg file
const texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(this.chosenImage)
this.svg = new PIXI.Sprite(texture)
this.svg.anchor.x = 0.8
this.svg.anchor.y = 0.8
this.svg.position.x = 400
this.svg.position.y = 300
this.svg.scale.x = this.selectedScale
this.svg.scale.y = this.selectedScale

this.container.addChild(this.svg)
```

- `chosenImage` is the svg file retrieved by using `import * as choesnImage from 'the-file-path'`
- `selectedScale` is the selected scaling value which can be changed dynamically thanks to VueJS
- You can check out my work [here](https://kevguy.github.io/D3-Svg-Comparison/) and its corresponding [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kevguy/D3-Svg-Comparison)
- The bunny logo is to verify when the scaling happens, it only applies to the SVG not the whole canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/936) you need to load svg like this to generate scaled svg texture.

```
PIXI.Texture.fromImage(this.chosenImage, undefined, undefined, newVal)
```

And need to clean texture cache then create new texture for every new scale change.

```
PIXI.utils.clearTextureCache()
```

Modified `SvgCompare.vue` on [gist](https://gist.github.com/alperencaliskan/251f62d6250bdc31f72cd3d2144df55f)